# Android Studio Google Pay Prepaid card

Tags: android, google-pay

I am integrating google pay in sandbox mode, but prepaid cards are not working. I receive the error:

> Request Failed Transaction Declined, to complete your transaction please provide Google with additional information by completing this form

I then get redirected to the Fix issues paying for Google products and services in support.google.

Real cards work perfectly, and i can add the prepaid cards to my google pay account just it fails when i try to use it at checkout. I have verified that i am using the correct billing address also. Not sure if maybe i need to add something in Android studio to get prepaid cards to work.

Comment: Hello javip,

There is not need to add any further dependency to the application or tool to Android Studio to integrate Google Pay on Android. Have you been able to do any progress following the steps in the support site? It'd be very helpful to learn a bit more about your use case:
What country are you operating from? 
What type of card are you using?
In which specific step do you get the error? (screenshots would help too)

Comment: using a visa prepaid card, working in the U.S....fails when attempting to checkout with google pay(After selecting the card in the google pay dialog and putting in my billing address)

Comment: Is the site public? It'd be useful to reproduce the error myself. Typically, cards are checked when added to Google Pay. In most common scenarios, if you were able to add it to Google Pay you should be able to transact with it.